# nvd3 / d3 - add point at intersection of 2 lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm making a tool to calculate return on investment and decided to use nvd3 to generate a chart.

However I'm having trouble understanding how I can add a circle or point where the 2 lines meet.

[image: current result, missing point at intersection]

To generate the graph I'm running the given method:

```
generateChart: function () {
    calculated.graph_values = roi_results.formatData();

    nv.addGraph(function () {
        var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .margin({ top: 30, right: 90, bottom: 100, left: 70 })
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true);

        chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel('Years');

        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('');

        $('#roi-graph').empty();

        d3.select('#roi-graph')
            .datum(calculated.graph_values)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
}
```

The formatData method just takes already calculated values and prepares the information for displaying on the graph:

```
formatData: function () {
    var graphData = [],
        xValue = 0;

    var savingsPerYear = _.reduce(calculated.yearlyData, function (agg, year) {
        agg.push({ x: xValue, y: biddle_helpers.roundNumber(year.saved_energy_price, 0) });
        xValue++;
        return agg;
    }, []);

    var investment = [],
        purchaseCost = input_values.get('product_purchase_cost') + input_values.get('product_installation_cost');
    for (var i = 0; i <= input_values.get('product_lifetime'); i++) {
        investment.push({ x: i, y: purchaseCost });
    }

    graphData.push({
        values: savingsPerYear,
        key: 'Savings per year',
    });
    graphData.push({
        values: investment,
        key: 'Investment',
        classed: 'dashed'
    });

    return graphData;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post until you have all the necessary information to hand. If you cannot post using a mobile device, then wait until you have access to a PC or laptop. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @halfer, sorry about that. I've updated the question

Comment: You may find the [Intersection Library](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm) helpful, which was developed by Kevin Lindsey. It hasn't seen an update lately, but it still works a treat and I have always preferred it over its forks, which also can be found.